# Database Trigger Insert from other table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables as described below. I made a trigger which must be executed on the `sgr_customer_group` table after a new insert into `sgr_customer` table:

After a new insert into `sgr_customer`, a new record with `id_customer` (Primary key of `sgr_customer`) and the constant 4 must be inserted into `sgr_customer_group` table.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER sgr_customer_trig
AFTER INSERT ON `sgr_customer` FOR EACH ROW
begin
       DECLARE id_exists Boolean;

       SELECT 1
       INTO @id_exists
       FROM sgr_customer
       WHERE sgr_customer.id_customer= NEW.id_customer;

       IF @id_exists = 1
       THEN
           Insert into sgr_customer_group (id_customer, id_group)VALUES(id_customer,4);
        END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Table definitions:

```
sgr_customer_group(id_group,id_customer#,id_group );
id_group:Primary Key
sgr_customer(id_customer,......); 
id_customer:Primary key
```

Great Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i have make that code but after inserting in sgr_customer table , nothinng is done in sgr_customer_group table ( any new row is added) . What's wrong in the trigger code ?

Comment: (1) I'm not sure you need that "exists" check; I don't think AFTER INSERT triggers execute if the insert was not completed successfully. (2) The VALUES you are inserting do not specify NEW.id_customer. (3) `@id_exists`  is not the same as the DECLAREd `id_exists`; the former is a "session" variable, that will be holding it's value between executions (on that connection), the latter is a local variable that you're never actually referencing.

Answer (score 0):

Everything @Uueerdo wrote in their comment to your question is correct, so the trigger can be simplified to:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER sgr_customer_trig
AFTER INSERT ON `sgr_customer` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO sgr_customer_group (id_customer, id_group) VALUES(NEW.id_customer, 4);
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```